# Cursor type change dynamically

Tags: javascript, asp.net, repeater, banner, mouse-cursor

I am working on project in which I am having some problem of loading cursor type dynamically.

I am having banners on my website. Now banners are bounded with anchor tag. Not if that banner have link then cursor type should be `Pointer` otherwise cursor will be `default`. I am binding banners using repeaters. And I have tried to do it onItenBound. But not getting the exact result.

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
    if (!drv["banner_url"].ToString().Equals(string.Empty))
    {
        ((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("banner")).HRef = Convert.ToString(drv["banner_url"]);
        ((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("banner")).Attributes.Add("url","yes");
        ((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("banner")).Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:default;");
    }
    else
    {
        ((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("banner")).HRef ="";
        ((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("banner")).Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
        ((HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("banner")).Attributes.Add("url", "no");
    }
}
```

and my aspx page code is

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt_primary" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="ws_images">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a id="banner" runat="server">
                            <img id="wows1"  style="cursor:default;" width="770" height="327" runat="server" src='<%# "banner/"+ DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"banner_image") %>' 
                                alt="" />
                        </a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a css `class`, say `curcor_pointer` which contain style rule `cursor:pointer !important;`.
In `repeater_ItemDataBound` handler just manage to add and remove the css class.
Try it.

```
.cursor_pointer
{
 cursor:pointer !important;
}
```